# Stored procedure takes too much time in if statement when i pass @ip='' and takes 0 sec with some value to @IP

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have below SP and its taking too much time and finally stopped with

```
EXEC MemberListing 1,20,'','','RegDate','Desc',0
```

while it works if pass any value to `@IP` parameter. don't know why.

```
Create PROCEDURE MemberListing
    @PageNum as Int,
    @PerPageResult as Int,
    @Username as nvarchar(50),
    @IP as varchar(50),
    @sortColumn as Varchar(50),
    @sortOrder as Varchar(4),
    @TotalCount as int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN   
    declare @Temp Table(RowNum int, id bigint, Username nvarchar(50), Email nvarchar(50), RegDate DateTime, Country varchar(25),
                            LastLogin DateTime, IsGoldMember varchar(1))
    declare @sort varchar(50)
    if @IP = ''
        BEGIN
            print 'if'
            SET FMTONLY OFF;
            Insert into @Temp
            Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by  
            case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end ASC

        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end DESC
            ) As RowNum, * From (   
            SELECT 
                m.id,m.login as Username,m.email as Email,m.registrationdate as RegDate,c.name as Country,m.lastlogindate as LastLogin,
                CASE WHEN (r.description='goldmember' or r.description='goldmember_forever') then 1 end As IsGoldMember 
            from member m 
            join country c on m.country_id = c.id
            join user_role ur on m.id=ur.member_id
            join role r on r.id=ur.role_id
            left join lastip l on m.id=l.user_id
            where r.description <> 'administrator' and m.login like @Username+'%'
            ) as aab
            Select * from @Temp Where RowNum> @PageNum-1 and RowNum<@PerPageResult+@PageNum
            order by 
            case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end ASC

        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end DESC
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            print 'else'
            SET FMTONLY OFF;
            Insert into @Temp
            Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by  
            case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end ASC

        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end DESC
            ) As RowNum, * From (   
            SELECT 
                m.id,m.login as Username,m.email as Email,m.registrationdate as RegDate,c.name as Country,m.lastlogindate as LastLogin,
                CASE WHEN (r.description='goldmember' or r.description='goldmember_forever') then 1 end As IsGoldMember 
            from member m 
            join country c on m.country_id = c.id
            join user_role ur on m.id=ur.member_id
            join role r on r.id=ur.role_id
            left join lastip l on m.id=l.user_id
            where r.description <> 'administrator' and m.login like @Username+'%' and l.address = @IP
            ) as aa
            Select * from @Temp Where RowNum> @PageNum-1 and RowNum<@PerPageResult+@PageNum
            order by 
            case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end ASC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'ASC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end ASC

        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'RegDate' then RegDate end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'Country' then Country end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then cast(null as datetime) when @sortColumn = 'LastLogin' then LastLogin end DESC
        ,   case when @sortOrder <> 'DESC' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'IsGoldMember' then IsGoldMember end DESC
        END 
END
```

i get below error in case i pass '' for @IP parameter.

```
if
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Procedure MemberListing, Line 24
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: If I understand your PRC well, in case of @IP = '' it should returns a wieder set of members. I think it is possible that the Username, Email or Country is longer in the member table then the "@Temp" table's definition. Match the column lenghts of "@Temp" wit table member.

Comment: If this is the case, then it should not work with @IP='::1' etc also.

Comment: @AndrásOttó: After correcting the column length, i am able to get the result but it takes 1:45 mins to execute it which is worst.

Comment: @AndrásOttó: in case @IP='some value', it takes 0 secs and in case @IP='', it takes 1:50 min. What's wrong here.

Comment: Probably the search on l.address = @IP changes the quryplan and takes extra time. Check the queryplan separetly of the two side of IF...ELSE, and you will see what is the difference, and may the Tuning Advisor will offer you an Index

Comment: okie, checking. And i would like to tell you one more thing. If i remove if else and apply the  l.address = @IP in the query and then i execute it with @IP='' ir @IP='some value', it takes 0 secs to fetch the results.

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer, because it is too much for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment the answer of your first question is:

If I understand your PRC well, in case of `@IP = ''` it should returns a wieder set of members. I think it is possible that the `Username, Email` or `Country` is longer in the member table then the `@Temp` table's definition. Match the column lenghts of `@Temp` wit table member.

Second answer for your question:

> In case @IP='some value', it takes 0 secs and in case @IP='', it takes
>   1:50 min. What's wrong here?

I think you should cut your prc to two part. Run both query (with @IP = '' and with = 'somevalue') and check the execution plans.

If you see, that it is working well with 'somevalue' and there is no need of an `INDEX`, I think your query is a victim of [parameter sniffing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx), which generally means that your execution plan is optimized to retrieve all the possibilites and it is not optimal to make a more selective search.

Probably it was optimized for a `full table scan` as it described in the article what I linked.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue as i don't have any DBA here.

Comment: Please read this article (link on parameter sniffing text), there is some advice how to deal with it. Section Action plan, idea 1) and 2) is fitting for your case I think.

Answer (score 0):

As per error message update:

You need to check data length of select query and make sure your @Temp table columns are defined correctly. For example; You could extend the column length of `Country varchar(25)` to `Country varchar(50)`

Also, I think your `CASE` statement doesn't make sense. What your `CASE` effectively doing is:

```
row_number() over (order by 0)
```

Also, you could declare your `@Temp` table as below with **`identity(1,1)`** column (ie; *`identity(seed,increment)`*) to get the row number without using `row_number()` function

```
declare @Temp Table(RowNum int identity(1,1), id bigint, Username nvarchar(50), 
                    Email nvarchar(50), RegDate DateTime, Country varchar(25),
                    LastLogin DateTime, IsGoldMember varchar(1))
```

Now you can get rid of `row_number()` function. And simplify insert (for `if` condition) as below

```
if (@IP = '')
begin
    insert into @Temp
    select m.id,m.login as Username,m.email as Email,m.registrationdate as RegDate,
           c.name as Country,m.lastlogindate as LastLogin,
           CASE when (r.description='goldmember' or r.description='goldmember_forever') 
                 then 1 end As IsGoldMember 
    from member m join country c on m.country_id = c.id
         join user_role ur on m.id=ur.member_id
         join role r on r.id=ur.role_id
         left join lastip l on m.id=l.user_id
    where r.description <> 'administrator' and m.login like @Username+'%'
    order by 
         case when @sortOrder = 'asc' and @sortColumn = 'id' then id  
              when @sortOrder = 'asc' and @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username  
              when @sortOrder = 'asc' and @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email
              ...
              when @sortColumn = 'id' then id desc
              when @sortColumn = 'Username' then Username desc
              when @sortColumn = 'Email' then Email decs
              ...
         end
     --Now your select query to select required row numbers
     --Note the change to your where clase to bring correct results.
     Select * from @Temp 
     Where RowNum > @PerPageResult*(@PageNum-1) and RowNum <= @PerPageResult*@PageNum
end else
begin
    --you could follow the same step here.
end
```

Comment: case statements are correct and its paging stored procedure so i can't leave row_number() function.

Comment: Yes they are but do they make sense? Here: `case when @sortOrder <> 'asc' then 0 when @sortColumn = 'id' then id end ASC` it will never evaluate `@sortColumn = 'id'`. I think you expecting `and` here. but the simplified version do the same without `row_number()`

Comment: What if i pass @sortColumn='id' :) and also, in case of custom paging the row_number() function must be according to sorting column so it make sense.

Comment: problem is not here and i can't leave case statements in paging stored procedure.

Comment: It is not a syntax error. BUT `"Your case statement won't be producing results as you expect"`. effectively what you are doing is `row_number() over (order by 0)`. I don't think I can explain you anymore ...

Comment: Dear i am not saying that its a syntax error or not. you are not focusing on my problem. It's not a primary focus that weather i get expected result or not, problem is that i am not getting any result while i am getting if
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Procedure MemberListing, Line 24
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

(0 row(s) affected). Are you getting my point now?

Comment: You just have added your error message, before it wasn't a proper question either. Check my updated answer.

Comment: And please read how to create a custom paging stored procedure with sorting and filtering. Without row_number() function, you can't create it.

Comment: Yes i can understand you can't. :-)